# Does $(1-\cos(x))/x^2$ have or deserve a name, like $sinc$ for $\sin(x)/x$?

Tags: trigonometry, special-functions

i think it's the “dual” of $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$, that is, $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac 1 2,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

they share some properties:

both have definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}dx = \pi$

on taylor series, both could be regarded as chopping the constant term then divided by x to "the order the first term"-th power, $\frac 1{1!} - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!} + ...$ for the sinc case, and $\frac 1{2!} - \frac{x^2}{4!} + \frac{x^4}{6!} - \frac{x^6}{8!} + ...$ for the cosine case.

it also appears in my recent (humble) study about 3D rotation. in a nutshell, to generate a rotation matrix from a rotation vector, let
$$\text{rotation vector }\vec{r}=\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix}, \theta = \lVert \vec{r}\rVert$$
$$\mathbf{C}=\text{“cross product matrix” of }\vec{r}=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-z&y\\z&0&-x\\-y&x&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{R}=\exp(\mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{I} + \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta} \mathbf{C} + \frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{\theta^2}\mathbf{C}^2$$

(note that $\mathbf{C}^3=-\theta^2\mathbf{C}$)

(also $\mathbf{R}=\exp(\theta\mathbf{K}) = \mathbf{I} + (\sin{\theta})\mathbf{K} + (1-\cos{\theta})\mathbf{K}^2$ where $\mathbf{K}$ is from the normalized rotation axis, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation))

where $\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\frac{1-\cos{\sqrt{x}}}{x}$ expands similarly and adds up to the whole pretty series of $\exp{(\mathbf C)}$, allowing us to bypass the normalization step.

---

btw, searching for the definition only gives a bunch of tutorials for evaluating its limit when $x \to 0$ (fyi, $\frac 1 2$).

there's also a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803550/equivalent-of-sinx-x-operatornamesincx-for-cosx-1-x) asking for the dual.

sorry for broken English...

Comment: Note that $$1-\cos x = 2\sin^2 \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)$$ So the function you wrote is actually $2 \operatorname{sinc}^2 \left(\dfrac{x}{2} \right)$.

Comment: @Zerox nah, the denominator is still x^2 but not (x/2)^2, so it doesn't work.. and fyi i've added their series expansions.

Comment: Indefinite integral $\pi$?

Comment: @FarterYang $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac{2\sin(x/2)^2}{x^2}=\frac{2\sin(x/2)^2}{2^2 (x/2)^2}=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{sinc}(x/2)^2$. So it does work minus the minor algebra error.

Comment: @TedShifrin oops, fixed

Comment: I find the remark of @Zerox is excellent ; you shouldn't have reacted negatively  like this: it differs only by a multiplicative constant $2$. A good lot of important concepts in maths are defined up to a constant...

Comment: @Ian nice, i missed that, thx! then the rest is... does it deserve a name, cuz it somehow appears.

Comment: @JeanMarie i agree, my brain failed in that minute (facepalm

Comment: I appreciate your last comment. Moreover it makes sense to have a function of the form $(...)^2$ as coefficient of a matrix itself a square.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2803558/305862